# Writing a correct rewrite rule .htcaccess and includes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a real simple website, no cms or anything (and i wish to keep it simple), the website structure is built on named folders with the corresponding content in an `index.php` inside it.

I managed to write a `.htaccess` with the following rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testSite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /testSite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

<s>Which gives me pretty urls just like i want, but lets say I go to a second sub page, etc `/testSite/subpage/secondsubpage` it instead redirects to `/testSite/secondsubpage`.</s>

**Edit:** Which gives me pretty urls just like i want, but lets say I go to a second sub page, etc `/testSite/subpage/secondsubpage` **by clicking a link** it doesnt continue to build the url and instead sends you to `/testSite/secondsubpage`.

My links on my sub-page looks like this `<a href="secondsubpage">Click me!</a>`

Also in the end I want the website to function like this: the sub index are to be included on the main index page body on navigation so that the header and footer remain the same. Feels very un-DRY having to include them on every sub page. Might be a separate question, but I'm not sure if that is handled by the `.htaccess` or php (php is not my main language).

**Side note:** I have researched ALOT and came nowhere with this, regex and "behind the scenes" things like `.htaccess` files is not the cup of tea for a frontender like me.

Comment: Does it actually redirect from `/testSite/subpage/secondsubpage` to `/testSite/secondsubpage` when you manually enter `/testSite/subpage/secondsubpage` into your browser's address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a link on (for example) `/testSite/subpage` that looks like

```
<a href="secondsubpage">Click me!</a>
```

then it'll lead to `/testSite/secondsubpage`. A link that doesn't start with `/` will effectively start in **the same folder** that the current page is in.

In order to link to `/testSite/subpage/secondsubpage`, then, the link could be absolute like this:

```
<a href="/testSite/subpage/secondsubpage">Click me!</a>
```

Absolute links, while longer, avoid all confusion. Alternatively, if you want it to still be relative, any link within `/testSite/` must look like:

```
<a href="subpage/secondsubpage">Click me!</a>
```

For a further example, to link to this page from a page in `/`:

```
<a href="testSite/subpage/secondsubpage">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: Haha alright, so theres no automagic way to do this? I suppose I could put another .htaccess file in my sub folders where i have alot of links

Comment: What would another .htaccess file accomplish there? The links need to be pointing to the correct locations before you can use rewrite rules to make your PHP handle those locations. (I might be misunderstanding your requirements?)

Comment: if you put another .htaccess in a folder with the same rule, forcing all requests through the index in that folder i wouldnt have to write double links like "/testSite/secondsubpage". At least thats is how i understand the use of htaccess files in folders.
As to your other question, no it takes me to the right page when entered, so I was quite wrong

Comment: Okay, so what's happening isn't a redirect at all. The problem is that the links are pointing to the wrong places - the .htaccess is just fine.

Comment: To elaborate: the purpose of rewrites in a .htaccess file is to change how links are followed. You have to decide on what your page URLs are going to be, and *then* use rewrites to route those URLs into your PHP code. Right now, all your URLs will look like `/testSite/something`. Since **no redirects are happening**, just rewrites, you can see where each link actually takes you by simply clicking it and looking in the browser address bar.

Comment: Misunderstanding on my part then, rewrite rule =/= redirecting. Ill figure something out with the information at hand :-)